# Difference between two same structure

Tags: meaning

Can you please explain difference between two structure below;

First is

> “It is my turn to drive “ .

This means that my turn to drive has come .

Second is

> “ It is my idea to buy a new car” .

And this means that buying a new car is my idea. 
Are my ideas correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the meaning you give for each sentence is correct. The structures are really the same; by beginning "It is my..." the speaker is claiming some ownership or right over the object - in one case asserting their right to take the next turn at driving (presumably according to some prior agreement or understanding) and in the other, claiming that he/she was first to suggest buying a new car. It would be unusual to use that sentence just to give the plain information that the idea of buying a car was in your mind.